# not able to connect mysql server

Tags: mysql

I have mistakenly deleted some of the dependent file for mysql when I am trying to use mysql command i am getting following error :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have tried reinstalling mysql-server but it still not resolved .

What should I do to bring back everything to normal condition.

EDIT: The operating system is UBUNTU .  the log file(var/log/mysql_logs) is of byte . Nothing is there.

Please check the screenshot in this question .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140816/downgrade-to-rails-2-3-from-3-1-1how-to

Comment: Make sure MySQL is started, for starters.

Comment: Did you kill old mysql process?

Comment: Please append you log files so we can see the exact log message. We are not able to read coffee grounds :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock exists, is a socket and accessible by the relevant parties? e.g.

```
 srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0
```

Your client is trying to connect via /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, but is this what the server is using? If you can get a network connection, try:

```
 show variables like '%SOCKET%'
```

to verify the path.

Check /etc/my.cnf, /etc/init.d/mysqld and /etc/sysconfig/mysql[d] to see if the socket path has been overridden.

Comment: There is no such file: etc/my.cnf

Comment: There is no such file: etc/my.cnf and also other are not available . Please check the screenshot AND mysqld.sock does not exist :(

Comment: Then backup your data and do an `apt-get --reinstall mysql-server` (this shouln't overwrite your data files - but just in case).

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried 'reinstalling', it may have not deleted completely. You haven't stated your OS, but I assume linux:

For RPM based:

```
rpm -e mysql mysql-server
```

You may also want to/have to delete all the data. I believe that is located at /var/lib/mysql

for deb/apt based:

```
apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
```

Again, data should be in /var/lib/mysql

This should be done especially if you've removed dependent files from the mysql installation.

Also, ensure that you've actually started the mysql process.